# Is there any way to edit any number of list inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary which has lists inside it.I created a variable to tell python how much lists do it need to create in the dictionary.
Here's the code:

```
dict = {}
for i in range(number_of_lists):
    dict[str(i)] = []
```

This code should produce a dictionary like this:

*number_of_lists = 3

```
{'0': [], '1': [], '2': []}
```

Then I need to edit the lists into:

```
{'0': [1, 2], '1': [2, 1], '2': [3, 2]}
```

How can I do this?

Also note that numbers in lists is just random...

Comment: `dict['0']=[1,2]` , `dict['1']=[2,1]` and so on ...

Comment: No sequence there.Just random numbers.

Comment: You might need to describe the problem a little more. It's not clear exactly what you're stuck on. It sounds like you're just asking "How do I add items to a list?" coupled with "How do I access the values of a dict?"

Comment: Why use a dictionary for that? A list of lists would the job in an easier way. Even the initialization would be simpler: ```lists = [[]] * number_of_lists```. Also note that ```dict``` is a reserved word.

Comment: What is the rule that says what numbers should be inside each list?

Comment: Please, take a look on ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and on ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks I got it.Thank you all so much. :)

Comment: Do you want to pick the keys and values from a list, and make a dict out of them? If so, does my answer make sense to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate through the list of keys and values to make your overall dictionary like so.

```
def get_dict(keys, values):

    dct = {}
    for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
        dct[key] = values[idx]
    return dct

print(get_dict(['0', '1', '2'], [[1, 2], [2, 1],  [3, 2]]))
#{'0': [1, 2], '1': [2, 1], '2': [3, 2]}
print(get_dict(['K', 'E', 'Y'], [[1, 2], [2, 1],  [3, 2]]))
#{'K': [1, 2], 'E': [2, 1], 'Y': [3, 2]}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm expecting! Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

Please try, other list commands used the same way

```
dict = {}
for i in range(number_of_lists):
    dict[str(i)] = []

a = 1
dict['name_of_list'].append(a)

print(dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by random ? Just any number or within a specific range ?

```
from random import randint

dict = {}
number_of_lists = 4
for i in range(number_of_lists):
    dict[str(i)] = [randint(0, x+1) for x in range(0,i+1)]
```